# VUE axios get API not found

Tags: python, django, vue.js, axios

I have an app Vue + Django. I try to send some data from vue to database using axios post method. Unfortunately console shows error:
    `GET http://localhost:8080/api/get_data/ 404 (Not Found)`

And the same happend in python console:
    `Not Found: /get_data/`

I have function get_data defined in my views and i added a path to urls:
`path('get_data/', views.get_data)`

In frontend it looks like this:

```
    addNewData() {
      axios.post("/api/get_data/", this.componentData.data).then(response => {
        console.log("ok");
      });
    }
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: In urls.py you have given `get_data/` but trying to access `/api/get_data/` you must change it to any one format.

Comment: It's still gives me the same error

Comment: Django runs as port `8000` by default not on `8080`

Answer (score 1):

`axios.post("/api/get_data/"` - this URL is relative to "current". That's why it is trying ot access `http://localhost:8080/...` where **8080** is the port of VUE app. Whereas Django app is running by default on **8000**.

You should use absolute URLs to access one app from another: to access Django app API from Vue app.

Use different config/env.var in your VUE app to refer to backend API in debug (localhost) and prod (domain name + http/https) modes, like:

```
axios.post(conf.BACKEND_URL + "/api/get_data/")
```

in your case, in debug mode it should be (expanded):

```
axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/get_data/")
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't used webpack proxyTable deal with '/api' ,you should add the backend address